# Eclipse não mostra dica de atributo java

Tags: eclipse, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Quando eu pressiono <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> e clico no *atributo*, o Eclipse não está mostrando a dica do atributo antes de Clicar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente o seguinte.

Vá em *Window* → *Preferences* → *Java* → *Editor* → *Content Assist* → *Advanced* e certifique-se que a opção `Java Proposals` esteja marcada, válido para os Eclipse Kepler e Luna.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: fui lá, e já estava marcado. O que faço ?

Comment: agora funcionou vlw ai amigo !